# function.include error when using a direct link

Tags: php, include

I am trying to substitute a calendar plugin for an old archive page of events. In `archive.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php get_header();
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$yourcat = get_category ($cat);
global $gateway_parent_id;


if ( $yourcat->slug == 'events' ){
include 'page-forum.php';
}else{

?>
```

when I change line 8 to
    `include 'http://www.mysite.com/events/';`
 I get the following errors:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /data/23/2/34/80/21912080/user/2412808/htdocs/wp-content/themes/ga/archive.php on line 8

Warning: include(http://www.mysite.com/events/) [function.include]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /data/23/2/34/80/21912080/user/2412808/htdocs/wp-content/themes/ga/archive.php on line 8

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://www.mysite.com/events/' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in /data/23/2/34/80/21912080/user/2412080/htdocs/wp-content/themes/ga/archive.php on line 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warnings pretty clear, allow_url_open is disabled so you can't open a url as a file so you can't include it. If the archive page is on your site why don't you do a file include?

Comment: It's recommended to use a local path instead of loading your own website's include files via an absolute URL. If you want to get rid of the errors, you can enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini file but there are many security issues and you might not be able to do that if you're using a shared host.

Comment: Can I use a relative path when the calendar page will be in a different directory than the archive.php?

Comment: @Chris Bishop: Sure. See my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution in Wordpress - this works for redirecting to an absolute url and avoids using htaccess:

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

$location is the url to direct to, $status is either 301 (permanent redirect) or 302 (temporary)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include the file via. url which is disabled in your server's PHP configuration. You can fix this by setting `allow_url_fopen` on in php.ini, or better use a file path instead.

To include the file via a file path use the full path to the file name relative to your current php file, using `../` as appropriate to go up directories. For example if I want to include `/root/test/save.php` from `/root/dir/working/go.php` I would use `include ('../../test/save.php');` or just `include('/root/test/save.php');`.

Comment: What if the page is simply events/ rather than events.php?

Comment: It depends on how your site is structured. If `events/` is a directory then you can include the `index.php` file within that directory, but otherwise you need to figure out what file `events/` goes to.

Answer (score 0):

[include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and its relatives take filesystem paths, not web paths relative to the document root. To get the parent directory, use `../`

For example, if the file you want to include is in a different directory than archive.php, say *includes*, you can do something like:

```
include('../includes/file.php');
```

If you begin with a /, an absolute system file path will be used (in other words: any path beginning with a slash will be an absolute path). Example:

```
include('/home/user/public_html/project/include/config.php');
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What if the page is simply events/ rather than events.php?